# Query returns NULL for current date

Tags: mysql

I want to query user quota for the current date. I am using the following code:

```
SELECT (SUM(acctinputoctets)+SUM(acctoutputoctets)) AS Total 
FROM radacct 
where (acctstarttime between  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') AND NOW() 
AND acctstoptime  between  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-%d') AND NOW()) 
AND radacct.username='%{User-Name}'
```

It works fine if there is an *acctstoptime* value in the table. But if the user has not disconnected yet (and has no previous session for the day), it returns NULL.

So how can I can get the value even if the user *acttstoptime* is null?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to consider `AcctStopTime` at all considering that it will be always null or after start time, so something like this is enough:

```
SELECT (SUM(IFNULL(acctinputoctets,0))+SUM(IFNULL(acctoutputoctets,0))) AS Total 
FROM radacct 
where acctstarttime >= CURDATE() 
AND radacct.username='%{User-Name}'
```

As simple as that would be enough for you.

By the way, I've tested this in my `radacct` PostgreSQL database, replacing just `ifnull` with `coalesce` and `curdate()` with `current_date` and it worked as expected. I cannot test it in MySQL because I don't have a freeradius daemon using it right now.

Answer (score -4):

```
SELECT (SUM(IFNUL(acctinputoctets,0))+SUM(IFNULL(acctoutputoctets,0))) AS Total 
FROM radacct 
where (acctstarttime=CURDATE())
AND (acctstoptime=CURDATE()) 
AND radacct.username='%{User-Name}'
```

Comment: From the OP's description and query, It looks like `acctstarttime` and `acctstoptime` are not just dates but may contain the time part as well. Matching a datetime value with just a date will only give you results for datetime values where the time part if 00:00. Another thing (probably the central one here) is that the OP is having trouble with rows where `acctstoptime` is NULL. You are certainly not addressing that issue.